# Apache sometimes doesn't reply to request

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

I got a strange problem with an apache behind another apache reverse proxy.

Our setup is like this:

```
client -> haproxy -> pfsense firewall -> apache cluster -> vm with apache (hosting a wordpress)
```

We do host other stuff behind the apache cluster (lots of tomcats) to which the apache cluster connects via ajp. Now the need to be able to host a simple wordpress page came up. I just installed an apache with php on a vm and told our apache cluster to work as a reverse proxy.

Everything works fine. Except when it doesn't.

Sometimes when a clients sends a request, it gets logged on the apache cluster. But the wordpress vm never answers and the clients get a "Bad Gateway (HTTP Error: 502). The request isn't logged on the wordpress vm, but when I look at the tcpdump I can see the incoming request.

I looked into the wordpress apache load and available workers. The Apache should be able to respond, it has almost no load.

What else might be wrong here? I'm completely out of Ideas.